# En un proyecto usando Lazy Loading y Suspense en React no logro renderizar un componente

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, lazy-loading

Espero que esten bien.

Tengo un problema realizando un proyecto en React, particularmente una suerte de react-router pero menos pretencioso solo para entender la dinamica de como funciona esa libreria por detrás. Sin embargo me topé con un problema al que no le encuentro una resolucion desde hace 2 dias.

La página carga su homepage sin problemas, sin embargo al querer ingresar a la otra ruta, se carga correctamente el fallback del suspense pero la página no. Todo lo que recibo es un mensaje por consola diciendo que no se puede convertir un objeto a un valor primitivo.

Si hago la prueba de renderizar el componente utilizando importacion estática el componente puede renderizarse sin problemas, pero al momento que intento realizar la importacion dinamica con lazy el navegador no lo renderiza.

Este es el código de mi App.jsx

```
import { lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import { HomePage } from "./pages/Home";
import { ROUTES } from "./logic/consts";
import { Router } from "./components/Router";
import { Route } from "./components/Route";

const LazyAbout=lazy(()=>import("./pages/About.jsx"));


function App() {
  return (
    <main>
      <Suspense>
      <Router routes={ROUTES}>
          <Route path='/' Component={HomePage} />
          <Route path='/about' Component={LazyAbout} />
      </Router>
      </Suspense>
    </main>
  )
}

export default App
```

Lo que mas me aflige del problema es que, leyendolo varias veces, no encuentro errores en la semántica del código. Es por eso que comparto esta consulta para ver si existe alguien que pueda tener un mejor acercamiento sobre el problema.

Gracias a todos de antemano!

Comment: Sería relevante detallar qué versiones de las librerías del código que muestras estás usando. Al margen de ello, puede ser que la propiedad `Component` esté mal escrita, ya que a priori se esperaría que esta fuera con minúsculas (`component`). Para ello, se requiere visibilizar el contenido de los componentes que importas en la pregunta.

Comment: Hola @KBeDev. La propiedad component (en minusculas) arroja un resultado indeseado (redirige siempre a mi 404).

No estoy utilizando mas librerias para este caso particular que las de React en 18.2.15 y path-to-regex en 6.2.1

Comment: Probaste con la propiedad [lazy](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#lazy)?